# How do I convert a table with team names and arrays of users per team to one user per row per team in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

how can i go from data like this [table in which column A has team names and column B has in each row an array with users of respective team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVKxH.png)

to this [table in which column A has team names and column B has one user per row related to its respective team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3zs4.png) in google sheets?

i tried

=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"|"&REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "[[]']", "")), "|"))

=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B2:B), "[[]']", ""),",")))

=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "[[]']", ""), ", "))

all suggestions from chat gpt, but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(split(tocol(map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,a&"|"&split(regexreplace(b,"\[|\]|'",),", "))),3),"|",0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: still geting an #error! :(

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet(recreating this error scenario), so that it would be easier for us to troubleshoot it directly.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OMjZ2qmzoJ6c1x5kzWVGz2QzQq8VEM5HVpkL37REaBY/edit?usp=sharing what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Sheet locale issue fixed. replaced **,** with **;**

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(u,SPLIT(B2:B,"[',] "),
       f,{TOCOL(IF(N(u)^0,A2:A)),TOCOL(u)},
       FILTER(f,INDEX(f,,2)<>"")))
```

[image]